How to Retrieve Profile Effect from the Discord User Object?
I want to retrieve the relatively new Profile Effect from a User, however it seems that the Profile Effect is not included in the User Object while the Avatar Decoration is.
I was unable to find any mention of the Profile Effect in the docs whatsoever. Is there a way to retrieve the Profile Effect from a User? and if not, why?
For clarification, I’m referring to the Profile Effect shown in this video: https://imgur.com/a/HS3BAgz.

it is included, it's in the link you gave

Also it's in the docs of discord.py

This is the Avatar Decoration and NOT the Profile Effect, which does NOT include the Profile Effect.

It is currently not possible to retrieve the profile effect of a user, as per the documentation. You can open a feature request discussion here.

For anyone looking into this in the future:
As pointed out in the comments, it is currently not possible to retrieve the Profile Effect of a user using the Discord API.
I’ve submitted a feature suggestion to address this limitation. If there are any updates or changes to this functionality, I’ll make sure to update this answer.

Iirc its in the Avatar decoration. You just need the keyword passthrough=true for the effect included. passthrough=false is only the decoration. E.g.
https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatar-decoration-presets/a_f081c6b2c85c5ebe5df42f1c24d45bb5.png?size=96&passthrough=false
or
https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatar-decoration-presets/a_f081c6b2c85c5ebe5df42f1c24d45bb5.png?size=96&passthrough=true

This is not what I'm looking for. For clarification I added a Video showing what exactly the Profile Effect is.
